# Does this sentence sound idiomatic: "I know here." to mean "I know this place."

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language, direct-objects

Imagine you came to a place where you suddenly remembered you had seen before. In this situation;

Can I say **"I know here"**?

Or do I have to say **"I know this place."**

In other words, can I say **"I know here."** to mean **"I know this place."**

Comment: No, it's not idiomatic. Without context it means very little.

Comment: You would be understood in that context, but I doubt a native speaker would say it.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker, Thanks for the comment. What would a native speaker say in that context?

Comment: "You would be understood in that context." That is potentially far fetched, "I know here" sounds like substantially broken English to me.

Comment: @EliHarold 's answer is what a native speaker might say. His comment here is right - essentially the same as mine: understood, but strange.

Answer (score 1):

> I know here.

is not idiomatic at all. The only good way I can think to say this is, in fact:

> I know this place.

Alternatives that are commonly used with slightly different meanings would include:

> I have been here before.

or

> I have seen this place before.